Google_Service_Plus_Person model domain property in new Google People API
I'm migrating the google/apiclient PHP library from v1 to v2. The previous version of the library had a model Google_Service_Plus_Person, which contained domain property. I'm trying to find the same property but in new API.
I've checked the Google People API docs, and found that Organization also has domain property. I want to somehow verify is that the same property that Person used to have.

If I understand you correctly you want to know if the information inside of the People API on the resource organization -> domain is the same as the Google_Service_Plus_Person showed on the domain resource.
As the configuration of Google Workspace changed and rearranged all the information about the accounts and users.
I can say that YES the DOMAIN information shown under ORGANIZATION in the Google People API is the same as the show on the Google_Service_Plus_Person domain property.

Thanks for the answer!
Yes, I believe you understood the question right. Do you know if I need to update my authorization scopes and include https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read as mentioned here (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)? Or scopes profile, email, openid should be enough?
Thanks again.

Yes you will need to include the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read

Cool, thanks for sharing the knowledge!
